# "Back here again in two years" or "Back here again after two years"

Tags: grammar, word-in-context

Which one's correct?

> "Back here again in ( ) years"

or

> "Back here again after ( ) years"?

Comment: What is your preferred option, and why? Show us that you've tried to answer the question on your own.

Comment: In addition to CowperKettle's suggested elaborations, it would be very helpful to add context. The decision of which preposition to use depends on what situation you are trying to describe.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is used when you have visited a place and going back there in several years.

The second one is used when you visited a place a number of years ago and you return there.